# Do javax.net.ssl.* VM arguments need to be migrated to jakarta.net.ssl.*?

Tags: java, truststore, jakarta-migration

Quarkus 3 has introduced Jakarta EE 10 that need to replace all the `javax.*` package with `jakarta.` package.

In our application we set these system properties at startup:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=...
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=...
```

Do we need to change it in `jakarta.net.ssl....` ?

Thanks

Comment: It does not replace all the `javax.*` packages. Affected packages are `javax.xml.bind`, `javax.servlet` and `javax.xml.ws` (perhaps some others), but AFAIK not `javax.net`.

Comment: Does `javax.net.ssl.*` come from Jakarta EE? No, therefore you don't need to (and must not, in fact) change those properties.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [Commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76255670/quarkus-3-jakarta-ee-10-and-javax-net-ssl-truststore#comment134473964_76255670)…

For any `javax` package, ask yourself if that class is from one of the Jakarta EE libraries? When you look up the latest Javadoc, does that page reside at the [Jakarta EE](https://jakarta.ee/) web site?

If so, change the package name to that which is documented. If not, leave the `javax` package as-is.

Java still has many packages in the `javax` namespace. This `x` naming is a leftover from older development practices during the early [Sun Microsystems](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Microsystems) days of Java’s history.

The package [`javax.net.ssl`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/javax/net/ssl/package-summary.html) is still a part of the current Java release, Java 21. Not in Jakarta EE.

---

The first versions of Jakarta EE did use the `javax.*` package naming, during the transitional period when Oracle Corp handed over Java EE technologies to the [Eclipse Foundation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_Foundation). My Answer here assumes you have moved on to the later versions of Jakarta EE that now use `jakarta.*` packages.

Comment: While the specific question is answered, the general recommendation of using Jakarta EE site is not helpful. The site doesn't have an obvious way to check whether a particular API moved to jakarta or not. Fo a developer it maybe easier to simply search for jakarta.net.sql related API on mvnrepository.com